# Weird unused static string declaration in C++ code

Tags: c++, optimization, static

Today in a popular problem solving site, i submitted a solution for a problem, then looked up a more faster code to find out what is the reason that his/her code is running faster than mine. The overall algorithm was same but the main difference i found is following.

```
static string x = [](){
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);
    return "";
}();
```

I also didn't understand what `cin.tie(nullptr)` doing here. I read about

[ostream* tie (ostream* tiestr);](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/tie/)

but couldn't figure out what this line is doing here.

Note that i've already know the fact that `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false)` stop wasting time to sync the i/o operation of `printf/scanf` with C++ counter part `cin/cout`.

I've already guessed that, the code inside the block get executed before even the main function ran, but i've no clue that what is the actual reason behind this construct.

Sorry for my bad english, your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This code initializes string with a lambda invocation. I guess the only point here is to mess with stdio anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have guessed most of it:

- it is executed before the main by initializing a static variable using a lambda
- it disables i/o related things that will slow down execution:

  - `std::ios::sync_with_stdio`
  - `cin.tie(nullptr)` will untie `cin` from `cout`. See below
- initializing a string like this is not costly because it won't cause a heap allocation for an empty string

from cplusplus.com:

> The tied stream is an output stream object which is flushed before
>   each i/o operation in this stream object

I guess this problem takes input from `cin` and you provide the answer on `cout`, from this point onward, writing to `cout` will be faster.

Comment: (Y) for your time and effort. @f4